# jQuery removed all elements?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have this function

```
$("tr#phaseRow"+data[2]).remove();
```

How can I test if I removed all elements tr?

Comment: ID selector only selects one element.

Comment: @undefined this is not an ID selector, though. If there are duplicate IDs (bad thing), it will pick them up.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, that's true for duplicate IDs, that's why I have downvoted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `$('tr').length==0`.

But prefer to use `$('#someId')` over `$('tr#someId')` : this will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if all tr elements have been removed like this:

```
if ($('tr').length === 0) {
  alert('No tr elements left'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test is to use http://www.jsfiddle.com . Go there, set up some sample `html` with a DOM that will mock your current DOM, make sure to include `jQuery 1.9` or your current version from the dropdown in the top left, place your script in the `javascript` section, and then click run. This will allow you to test your javascript (jQuery) code.

To do this in code, you could do this:

```
$("tr#phaseRow"+data[2]).remove();
if( $("tr#phaseRow"+data[2]).length > 0 ){
 /* elements not removed */ 
}//although it is unlikely your elements will remain
```